# Check response using urllib2

Tags: python, json, api, opencore

I am trying access a page by incrementing the page counter using opencorporates api. But the problem is there are times when useless data is there. For example in the below url for jurisdiction_code = ae_az I get webpage showing just this:

```
{"api_version":"0.2","results":{"companies":[],"page":1,"per_page":26,"total_pages":0,"total_count":0}}
```

which is technically empty. How to check for such data and skip over this to move on to next jurisdiction?

This is my code

```
import urllib2
import json,os

f = open('codes','r')
for line in f.readlines():
   id = line.strip('\n')
   url = 'http://api.opencorporates.com/v0.2/companies/search?q=&jurisdiction_code={0}&per_page=26&current_status=Active&page={1}?api_token=ab123cd45' 
   i = 0
   directory = id
   os.makedirs(directory)
   while True:
      i += 1
      req = urllib2.Request(url.format(id, i))
      print url.format(id,i)
      try:
        response = urllib2.urlopen(url.format(id, i))
      except urllib2.HTTPError, e:
        break
      content = response.read()
      fo = str(i) + '.json'    
      OUTFILE = os.path.join(directory, fo)
      with open(OUTFILE, 'w') as f:
        f.write(content)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interpret the response you get back (you already know it's json) and check if the data you want is there.

```
...
content = response.read()
data = json.loads(content)
if not data.get('results', {}).get('companies'):
    break
...
```

Here's your code written with Requests and using the answer here.  It is nowhere near as robust or clean as it should be, but demonstrates the path you might want to take.  The rate limit is a guess, and doesn't seem to work.  Remember to put your actual API key in.

```
import json
import os
from time import sleep
import requests

url = 'http://api.opencorporates.com/v0.2/companies/search'
token = 'ab123cd45'
rate = 20  # seconds to wait after rate limited

with open('codes') as f:
    codes = [l.strip('\n') for l in f]


def get_page(code, page, **kwargs):
    params = {
        # 'api_token': token,
        'jurisdiction_code': code,
        'page': page,
    }
    params.update(kwargs)

    while True:
        r = requests.get(url, params=params)

        try:
            data = r.json()
        except ValueError:
            return None

        if 'error' in data:
            print data['error']['message']
            sleep(rate)
            continue

        return data['results']


def dump_page(code, page, data):
    with open(os.path.join(code, str(page) + '.json'), 'w') as f:
        json.dump(data, f)


for code in codes:
    try:
        os.makedirs(code)
    except os.error:
        pass

    data = get_page(code, 1)
    if data is None:
        continue

    dump_page(code, 1, data['companies'])

    for page in xrange(1, int(data.get('total_pages', 1))):
        data = get_page(code, page)
        if data is None:
            break

        dump_page(code, page, data['companies'])
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that actually this example is *not* "technically empty."  It contains data and is therefore technically not empty. The data just does not include any fields that are useful to you. :-)

If you want your code to skip over responses that have uninteresting data, then just check whether the JSON has the necessary fields before writing any data:

```
content = response.read()
try:
    json_content = json.loads(content)
    if json_content['results']['total_count'] > 0:
        fo = str(i) + '.json'    
        OUTFILE = os.path.join(directory, fo)
        with open(OUTFILE, 'w') as f:
            f.write(content)
except KeyError:
    break
except ValueError:
    break
```

etc.  You might want to report the ValueError or the KeyError, but that's up to you.